# C++ - BMI calculation unexpected

Tags: c++, return

In my recent project, simple at short, I am calculating BMI.

I am using a single dimension array for the weight and height (double types)

To calculate the BMI, I use a function with the equation as a return value.

The problem is the result which is far beyond the value of a BMI (example: 20456)

If an acceptable question, would returning the result of the BMI calculation be the source of the problem?

Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<string>

double BMI(double height, double weight);

int main()
{
    SetConsoleTitle("Body Mass Index");

    double BMIinput [2];
    std::string Name;

    std::cout << "Enter your height (inches): "; 
    std::cin >> BMIinput[0]; 
    system("CLS");
    std::cin.ignore();

    std::cout << "Enter your weight (pounds): "; 
    std::cin >> BMIinput[1]; 
    system("CLS");
    std::cin.ignore();

    std::cout << "Enter your name: ";  
    std::getline(std::cin, Name); 
    system("CLS");

    std::cout << "Name: " << Name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "BMI: " << BMI(BMIinput[0], BMIinput[1]) << std::endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    system("CLS");

    return 0;
}

double BMI(double height, double weight)
{
    return (height * height / weight) * 703;
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code.  It is hard to read with everything flushed to the left margin.  Also, why `#include <Windows.h>`?

Comment: *would returning the result of the BMI calculation be the source of the problem?* -- You should have unit tested your function first with known data.  If it works properly when unit tested, then the function isn't the problem.

Comment: Note taken. With your question, <Window.h>, it's simple used for personal visual representation (SetConsoleTitle) .

Comment: Here is an [example of unit testing](http://ideone.com/zx6KoR).  As you can see, there is something wrong with the function calculation.  Once you fix that, *then* you use it in your larger application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BMI is calculated with weight over height squared. Your program calculates the inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula for BMI is wrong. 72*72/210*703 (six foot tall, 15 stone) gives about 17,000.  You need weight divided by height squared.